# Best practice for stream processing with fuzzy matching dedupe

Tags: apache-kafka, bigdata, apache-kafka-streams

I'm designing a data pipeline that starts with flat files that are read. each line in a file is a single record.

Once loaded, each record will be parsed, transformed and enriched. This happen independent of other records.

As a final step, I would want to dedupe records based of fuzzy matching of several record's fields. To do this I would like to get all combinations of 2 records.

currently I use sql table as a buffer. My table contains all records and I join the table with itself, `on` the conditions that keys are different, and fuzzy matching on name with `sounds like`:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_tblSoundsLikeName AS
SELECT DISTINCT clients1.client_name client_name1,
                clients1.client_id client_id1,
                clients2.client_name client_name2,
                clients2.client_id client_id2,
FROM tblClients clients1 
  JOIN tblClients clients2 
    ON clients1.client_name != clients2.client_name
       AND clients1.ban_id < clients2.ban_id
       AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(clients2.client_name,' ',1) SOUNDS LIKE SUBSTRING_INDEX(clients1.client_name,' ',1)
```

The records in temp_tblSoundsLikeName represents duplicates and I will merge them in tblClients.

I was thinking of using Kafka Streams, which I haven't used in the past. When a message `M` (representing record `R`) arrive to the dedupe topic, I would like my application to consume it and as a result to generate a message containing the information from `R` and from another message `R'`, where `R'` is any message that arrived in the dedupe stage in the past 5 hours. these messages, containing the combinations for 2 messages, should be sent to another topic, where they can be filtered by matching and fuzzy matching conditions, and the final stage is to merge duplicates records and push merged records to RDBMS with kafka connect JDBC.

I am not sure however how to create messages for all such `R` and `R'` combinations. 
Is this possible?
Is this a good use case for Kafka Streams?

Answer (score 2):

A starting point for de-duping with Kafka's Streams API is `EventDeduplicationLambdaIntegrationTest.java` at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples (direct link for Confluent Platform 3.3.0 / Apache Kafka 0.11.0: [EventDeduplicationLambdaIntegrationTest.java](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/3.3.0-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/EventDeduplicationLambdaIntegrationTest.java)).

The method `isDuplicate` controls whether or not a new event is considered to be a duplicate:

```
private boolean isDuplicate(final E eventId) {
  long eventTime = context.timestamp();
  WindowStoreIterator<Long> timeIterator = eventIdStore.fetch(
      eventId,
      eventTime - leftDurationMs,
      eventTime + rightDurationMs);
  boolean isDuplicate = timeIterator.hasNext();
  timeIterator.close();
  return isDuplicate;
```

The `eventIdStore` is a so-called "state store", and it allows you to remember information from past events so that you can make "duplicate yes/no?" decisions.

> When a message M (representing record R) arrive to the dedupe topic, I would like my application to consume it and as a result to generate a message containing the information from R and from another message R', where R' is any message that arrived in the dedupe stage in the past 5 hours. these messages, containing the combinations for 2 messages, should be sent to another topic, where they can be filtered by matching and fuzzy matching conditions, and the final stage is to merge duplicates records and push merged records to RDBMS with kafka connect JDBC.

One option you have is to do the "given a new `R`, let's find all `R'` messages, and then de-dupe" in one step, i.e. do this in one processing step (similar to what the example above does, using a so-called `Transformer`), rather than creating a bunch of new downstream messages, which leads to write amplification (`1 * R => N * "(R/R')"` downstream messages).  The state store can be used to track all prior messages, including the various `R'` you are interested in when `R` arrives.

Comment: @michael-g-noll thanks for your answer. I would like duplicates to be matched by fuzzy matching (for example string edit distance). I can see how a state store will be useful if I wanted exact match, but how would I use a state store to get various `R'` for fuzzy match? For example, if `R=Michael` I would like to dedupe `R'1 = michael , R'2 = Michale , R'3 = Michele`

Comment: You could implement a custom state store that would allow you to pass in "Michael", and return you the list of entries that fuzzy-match "Michael" (like michael, Michale, Michele).  See e.g. `ProbabilisticCountingScalaIntegrationTest` at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples for a demonstration on how to implement your own custom state store (this specific example is different than your use case, but the point is that you can plug in your own state stores, like one that's optimized to implement fuzzy matching).